# Homomorphisms between additive and multiplicative groups of fields

Tags: field-theory

Inspired by this question ([In a finite field, is there ever a homomorphism from the additive group to the multiplicative group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153967/in-a-finite-field-is-there-ever-a-homomorphism-from-the-additive-group-to-the-m/1153971#1153971)), I'm wondering for what fields there exists a non-trivial homomorphism from the additive group to the multiplicative group.  As noted in the question linked above, such homomorphisms exist for $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ and a simple argument (given in my answer to the above question) shows that they do not exist for finite fields.  The same argument also implies that no such homomorphism exists for algebraic closures of finite fields.

Is it known when such homomorphisms exist in general?  Are there any examples that are not isomorphic to subfields of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The relevant term for this idea would be [an exponential field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_field), which is a field equipped with such a homomorphism. I don't know anything about them except the name.

Comment: Interesting!  Too bad that page doesn't give any new examples.

Comment: Although I don't understand all the details of the argument, the answer to "are there examples not isomorphic to subfields of $\Bbb C$" is almost certainly *yes*, because the constraints of an exponential field form a first order language with an infinite model, which must thus have models of every infinite cardinality.