# $F$ be a field of non-zero prime characteristic $p$ , is it true that there is only one group homomorphism $f:(F,+) \to (F$ \ $\{0\},.)$?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, positive-characteristic

Suppose $F$ be a field of non-zero characteristic $p$ , is it true that there is only one group homomorphism $f:(F,+) \to (F$ \ $\{0\},.)$ ? I have tried taking $x \in F$ , then $px=0$ , so

$(f(x))^p=f(px)=f(0)=1$ , so $f(x)$ has finite order for every $x \in F$ ,   $f(x) \in (F$ \ $\{0\},.)$ , and

$o(f(x))|p$ . But then I am stuck . Please help

Comment: Oops. You don't assume the field to be finite. I was a bit trigger-happy there. Reopening. [The related thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1153967/11619) may still be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $x^p-1=(x-1)^p$. This allows us to determine which elements have order $p$.

Comment: The field is of characteristic $p$, not order $p$. The field may not even be finite.

Comment: @Amudhan thanks, this hint should be more appropriate.